# Azure Cloud Shell - No existing storage accounts available

Tags: azure

I have an Azure account which the subscription doesn't allow me to create new resources, so I can't create directly a storage for Cloud Shell.
So I ask one of my colleague to do it, he did create a storage for Cloud Shell and managed to connect to Cloud Shell.
Then I tried the Cloud Shell Advanced Settings to specify the Storage Account my colleague created. Unfortunately I see the error tooltip : No existing storage accounts available.
My colleague promoted me as Contributor then Owner of the Storage account, but it still doesn't work. He tried to unmount his cloud drive without any more success for me.
Does anyone know how use a Storage Account create by another person to connect to Cloud Shell?

EDIT:
The created storage account is a

- Storage (general purpose v1)
- Locally-redundant storage (LRS)
- Resource group: cloud-shell-storage-westus
- Storage name: csxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- Storage location: Location West US
- File Share: cs-mycolleaguename-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[image]

Comment: Is this a general purpose storage account, or a blob only storage account? Cloud shell requires Azure files which isn't present in the blob only version.

Comment: @SamCogan, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how use a Storage Account create by another person to
>   connect to Cloud Shell?

In your scenario, you should ask your colleague to create a storage account in that **location** same as your resource group.

Also should create Azure file share in that storage account, then we can use Azure portal to create new cloud shell with existing storage account and Azure file share, like this:

Select **Show advanced settings**:
[image]

Then we can select your storage account and file share, like this:

[image]

**Note**:

In the last line, we can find the cloud shell requirement, we should create a storage account in that location same as your resource group(In my test require to create a storage account in Central India), and the storage account should be LRS or GRS.

In my test, I grant **Reader** permission of `resource group` to new user, the **Contributor** permission of that `storage account` to new user, it works for me.

More information about deploy Azure cloud shell, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks to your answer I realised I didn't have persmission to access the resource group of the storage account. So my colleague granted me the Reader permission, but I still don't have "No existing storage accounts available". I added more info and a screenshot.

Comment: Granting Reader permission to the resource group of the storage account allows me now to select the `cloud-shell-storage-westus` resource group to attach the storage. Thanks buddy, I made it thanks to you!